# Change icon color if condition

Tags: sapui5

I am using a list that prints data from a model and one should have an icon. The thing is that the icon changes depending on the value and I should also change its color.

I have in my view :

```
<ObjectListItem title="State" type="Active" number="{/Data/8/state}"
icon="{= ${/Data/8/state}.toUpperCase() === 'OK' ? 'sap-icon://accept' : 
'sap-icon://decline' }"></ObjectListItem>
```

Options like addStyleClass doesn't seem to work. I have changed the color by adding css to the id that SAP adds to the Icon, but since it has to change according to the value I don't know how to achieve it.
Another option was to add color directly to these two icons but I wasn't able to add the classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CustomData` and then create a css selector to match it:

```
<ObjectListItem title="State" type="Active" number="{/Data/8/state}"
icon="{= ${/Data/8/state}.toUpperCase() === 'OK' ? 'sap-icon://accept' : 
'sap-icon://decline' }">
<customData>
  <core:CustomData writeToDom="true" key="class" value="{= ${/Data/8/state}.toUpperCase()}" />
</customData>
</ObjectListItem>
```

This will render your control with an additional `data-class` attribute (actually, `data-{key}`, where `key` is the `key` that you defined on your `core:CustomData`tag).

You can then match that with the CSS selector

```
[data-class='OK'] {
  color: blue !important; 
}
[data-class='NOT-OK']{
  color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I like your approach but it isn't working. It gives me an error: CustomData with key class should be written to HTML of Element sap.m.ObjectListItem#__item15 but the value is not a string. - and no data-class is added

Comment: I've tried writing directly the value : key="class" value="OK" and the error is gone, but no class is added

Comment: @lorenag83 what is the html output like? the `data-class` attribute should be added to the `<li>`tag. You can try to run `$("[data-class='OK']")` on the chrome dev tools (or the equivalent in your browser) and see if it returns something.

Comment: it seems to be adding it to the List (<li> tag) and then the class gets overwritten. I have inside <li> class=sapMLIBContent, sapMObjLTopRow, sapMOBjLIconDiv and finally.sapMObjLIcon which seems to be overwriting the color

Comment: Following your example, I've finally added the SapClass to the style [data-coloricon="No"] .sapMObjLIcon and it works !