# SAPUI5 - How to change style of FeedListItem according to the model data?

Tags: sapui5

I have a FeedList in Xml :

```
<List
id="msgList"
showSeparators="Inner"
items="{msgData>/msgData}" >
<FeedListItem
    sender="{msgData>UserName}"
    icon="{msgData>userPicture}"
    senderPress="onSenderPress"
    iconPress="onIconPress"
    iconDensityAware="false"
    info="{msgData>Type}"
    timestamp="{msgData>Date}"
    text="{msgData>Text}"
    class="{msgData>Type}"
    maxCharacters="1000"/>
```

And i need each feed item to change style according to the data that i receive from the model

```
var oDate = new Date();
var msgData = { msgData:[{
    Title: "",
    Text: "Loading...",
    UserName: "AyTee",
    userPicture:"image.png"
}]};
var oModelMockIntention = new JSONModel(msgData);
this.fragment.setModel(oModelMockIntention, "msgData");
```

**What is the best way to do it?**

Comment: You cannot bind 'class' attribute to the model. Either use a build-in property like icon or type or manually add / remove the css classes you need on model change

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change icon color if condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44393300/change-icon-color-if-condition)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a formatter in text property of FeedListItem and in the method you can use this instance and use addStyleClass and removeStyleClass methods to update the style of that particular FeedListItem as mentioned below:

```
 <List
id="msgList"
showSeparators="Inner"
items="{msgData>/msgData}" >
<FeedListItem
    sender="{msgData>UserName}"
    icon="{msgData>userPicture}"
    senderPress="onSenderPress"
    iconPress="onIconPress"
    iconDensityAware="false"
    info="{msgData>Type}"
    timestamp="{msgData>Date}"
    text="{parts: ['msgData>Text', 'msgData>Type'],formatter:'.updateColor'}"
    maxCharacters="1000"/>
```

Inside the controller of the view you can have the method as mentioned below:

```
 updateColor:function(text, type){
       this.addStyleClass(type);
       return text;
    }
```